# mupdf - invalid use of 'static' in linkage specification

Tags: c++, gcc, waf, mupdf

I'm trying an experiment with [waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf/) (the build system) on [mupdf](http://www.mupdf.com/).

I've encountered a compiler error when compiling [mupdf\fitz\dev_gdiplus.cpp](http://code.google.com/p/sumatrapdf/source/browse/trunk/mupdf/source/fitz/gdiplus-device.cpp).

```
..\..\..\mupdf\fitz\dev_gdiplus.cpp:1170:12: error: invalid use of 'static' in linkage specification

 extern "C" static void
```

The offending code (this is one instance; there are many):

```
extern "C" static void
fz_gdiplus_fill_path(fz_device *dev, fz_path *path, int evenodd, const fz_matrix *ctm,
    fz_colorspace *colorspace, float *color, float alpha)
{
    GraphicsPath *gpath = gdiplus_get_path(path, ctm, false, evenodd);
    Brush *brush = gdiplus_get_brush(dev, colorspace, color, alpha);

    ((userData *)dev->user)->started = true;
    ((userData *)dev->user)->graphics->FillPath(brush, gpath);

    delete brush;
    delete gpath;
}
```

This was the compiler call:

```
['C:\\MinGW64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe', '-fpermissive', '-IC:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\SumatraPDF-2.3.2-source\\sumatrapdf-2.3.2\\build\\temp\\debug\\mupdf\\fitz', '-IC:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\SumatraPDF-2.3.2-source\\sumatrapdf-2.3.2\\mupdf\\fitz', '-IC:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\SumatraPDF-2.3.2-source\\sumatrapdf-2.3.2\\build\\temp\\debug\\mupdf', '-IC:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\SumatraPDF-2.3.2-source\\sumatrapdf-2.3.2\\mupdf', '-IC:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\SumatraPDF-2.3.2-source\\sumatrapdf-2.3.2\\build\\temp\\debug\\mupdf\\pdf', '-IC:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\SumatraPDF-2.3.2-source\\sumatrapdf-2.3.2\\mupdf\\pdf', '-IC:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\SumatraPDF-2.3.2-source\\sumatrapdf-2.3.2\\build\\temp\\debug\\mupdf\\xps', '-IC:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\SumatraPDF-2.3.2-source\\sumatrapdf-2.3.2\\mupdf\\xps', '-IC:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\SumatraPDF-2.3.2-source\\sumatrapdf-2.3.2\\build\\temp\\debug\\ext\\freetype2\\include', '-IC:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\SumatraPDF-2.3.2-source\\sumatrapdf-2.3.2\\ext\\freetype2\\include', '-IC:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\SumatraPDF-2.3.2-source\\sumatrapdf-2.3.2\\build\\temp\\debug\\ext\\jbig2dec', '-IC:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\SumatraPDF-2.3.2-source\\sumatrapdf-2.3.2\\ext\\jbig2dec', '-IC:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\SumatraPDF-2.3.2-source\\sumatrapdf-2.3.2\\build\\temp\\debug\\ext\\libjpeg-turbo', '-IC:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\SumatraPDF-2.3.2-source\\sumatrapdf-2.3.2\\ext\\libjpeg-turbo', '-IC:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\SumatraPDF-2.3.2-source\\sumatrapdf-2.3.2\\build\\temp\\debug\\ext\\openjpeg', '-IC:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\SumatraPDF-2.3.2-source\\sumatrapdf-2.3.2\\ext\\openjpeg', '-DWAF=1', '-DVERSION="0.1"', '-DINLINE_MACRO=1', '-DHAVE_STDINT_H=1', '-DHAVE_STRING_H=1', '-DHAVE_STDIO_H=1', '-DDEBUG=1', '..\\..\\..\\mupdf\\fitz\\dev_gdiplus.cpp', '-c', '-o', 'mupdf\\fitz\\dev_gdiplus.cpp.1.o']
```

I suspect this is something to do with gcc, rather than the code. 
What's wrong with the code? What switches/flags need to be given to gcc to resolve the issue?

I'm using gcc (rev3, Built by MinGW-builds project) 4.8.1, on Windows 7 64bit.

Disclaimer: I don't understand c++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can duplicate the error with the following:

```
extern "C" static void f()
{
}
```

I can resolve the error by slightly changing the code to:

```
extern "C"
{
    static void f()
    {
    }
}
```

Seems like the compiler should be a little smarter here but at least it can be worked around.

Comment: Note that this makes zero sense though. How should a `static` even have external linkage?

Comment: @NikosC. if you understand the `extern "C"` keyword it makes partial sense -- resulting in an error is what does not make sense. Read the comment I have beneath your post for a little more info.

Comment: From what I understand, in mupdf, there are C functions which call some of the functions defined in the C++ file.

Comment: @dilbert You cannot call `static` functions from outside the file they are defined in. That's what `static` means. So it's weird.

Comment: Is it possible that msvc handles this differently than gcc?

Comment: @dilbert I'd say "obviously" :-) It's either ignoring one of the specifiers, or creates a function with C-linkage that cannot be called from C (or anywhere else). Which, again, doesn't make sense, but hey. It's best to send a note to the authors of that code though; they should be interested to know that GCC 4.8 can't compile their code.